# Need assistance with creating multilevel context menu for firefox Add-on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox-addon

Whenever I click on the US ID it will always take me to CA ID page.

Please help me correct the background code.

Thank you.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Amazon",
    "description": "Search on Amazon",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "48": "logo_48.jpg"
            },
    "permissions":["contextMenus"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: "US",
    title: "A US",
    contexts: ["selection"]
});


browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: "CA",
    title: "A CA",
    contexts: ["selection"]
});


//add action listener to the context menu
browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(contextMenuAction);

function contextMenuAction(info, tab) {



    const url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=";

    browser.tabs.create({url: url});
        }


browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(contextMenuAction);

function contextMenuAction(info, tab) {



    const url = "https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=";

    browser.tabs.create({url: url});
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added two listeners to any contextMenu item that may be clicked. So, you have two options:

#### Solution #1

Pass a function to the `onclick` option for each item

```js
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "US",
  title: "A US",
  contexts: ["selection"],
  onclick: function () {
    browser.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" })
  }
})

// do the same for the other contextMenu item created
```

#### Solution #2

Add a single listener and check which contextMenu item was selected using the menuItemId property.

```js
function contextMenuAction(info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId === "US") {
    browser.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" })
  }

  if (info.menuItemId === "CA") {
    browser.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=" })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much but both are not working. onclick is not working is 1st solution and in 2nd solution I have tried that earlier i'm not getting the multi-levels in the context menus. Please assist me.

Comment: I'm able to execute with 1st solution. But i'm not able to do this part "contexts: ["selection"]" i'm not able to search the selected text on .com or .ca. It will just land on the Homepage not on the respective keyword search page. Can you please help me with executing that.

Comment: Thank you..Made the necessary changes it is working properly.